# How to use jQuery to store number inputs to variables and performing calculation to update number input again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a BMI calculator using HTML and jQuery.

```
<form id="bmicalc">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>BMI Calculator:</legend>
        <p>
            <label>Height:
                <input type="number" id="height1" min="3" max="7">ft
                <input type="number" id="height2" min="0" max="11">in</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Weight:
                <input type="number" id="weight" min="1" max="1400">lb</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>BMI:
                <input id="bmi" type="number" min="1" max="200">
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="tehbaton" value="Check your BMI">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js">
var height = $("#height1").val()*12 + $("#height2").val(); //Height in Inches
var weight = $("#weight").val();
$("#tehbaton").click(function(){
    $("#bmi").val(703*weight/(height^2));
});
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzD9C/

I originally wanted the calculation to be performed on keyup but decided I didn't know enough to do that. So I'm keeping it simple for now to just update the third input field upon clicking the submit button.

But as it is now, clicking the button doesn't do anything.

The equation for calculating BMI is: 
BMI = ( Weight in Pounds / ( Height in inches x Height in inches ) ) x 703

Comment: can write code inside a script tag that has `src` set. Close `jquery.js` tag, add another tag for your code

Comment: i think what @charlietfl meant was that you CANT have javascript inside of a `<script>` tag that has its `src` attribute set. Also if you fix that and move your var's inside the click function it should work. check out this update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzD9C/4/

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks for helping charlietfl and clarifying that Chausser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#tehbaton").click(function () {
    if($("#height1").val() && $("#height2").val() && $("#weight").val()){
        var height = Number($("height1").val()) * 12 + Number($("height2").val());
        var weight = $("#weight").val();
        $("#bmi").val((703 * weight) / Math.pow(height,2));
    }
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/uzD9C/2/)

Comment: Great! It works. Would you be able to explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: First, your declare height and weight out of click event. So they always equal 0 and they're not depend on dropdownlist value when you change. Second you use height^2 instead of Math.pow(height,2).

Comment: Thank you! I also found another problem. It seems var height is concatenating the height1 and height2 inputs, which it shouldn't do since the + operator should be reading them as numbers. What's going on?!

Comment: I fixed it by putting a `* 1` after `$("height2").val()`. Interesting that this would be a problem. So is .val taking the input as strings unless you do some math operations with it?

Comment: My mistake! Sorry. Let try it Number($("height2").val()) or parseInt($("height2").val())